# url passing variables do not show the proper values passed

Tags: php, url, random

Please help,

I am using **XAMPP** as web server,but when I am passing variables(an id actually) through header 
`(header?act=edit&id=".$variable."')`

and I do $_GET() for the second variable it shows something like this `:id/random~1390392643684`

I don't really know how to fix this.

In one page I have the link that I have mentioned above`(header?act=edit&id=".$variable."')` and in other page I am getting the variables passed in header `$othervariable=$_GET['id'];` when I echo **$othervariable** it shows the value I have passed together with `random~1390392643684`. For example if **$othervalue=2** it shows `2/random~1390392643684` –

Thank you in advance.

Comment: probably some auto-generated string to prevent page caching?

Comment: What is in the `$variable`?

Comment: Maybe the solution is to use `rawurlencode()` on your variable?

Comment: $variable is the name of the variabl lika $a=2

Comment: i think that maybe is some xampp config , because i have been programming in a lot of time and this never happened